# Pass dynamic parameters to Gradle Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I am using the Gradle Jenkins plugin to create a Jenkins Job that executes a Gradle build.
I have a couple of parameters that are always required and these are passed to a Jenkins "Parameterized build". These parameters are correctly passed to gradlew.bat with the following format:

```
-DParam1=value1
```

Now there are some additional parameters that are dynamic in nature and I'd prefer to use a single Jenkins parameter such as "AdditionalParamters" and pass these values like so:

```
 "-DoptionalParam1=value1 -DOptionalParam2=value2".
```

If I use such a parameter, then the value passed to Gradle is "-DAdditionalParamters=-DoptionalParam1=value1 -DOptionalParam2=value2" and this is not what I'd intended to pass.

So are there any means of passing multiple System parameters to gradle by using a single Jenkins parameter?

Comment: Why are you wanting to pass multiple system properties with one key? What's the advantage?

Comment: @BenGreen, We have over a 50 distinct configuration properties most of which have defaults. However, we may need to change the default values of these through setting a system property. So if we have to change, say the 48th and 49th property, i can set it as -DoptionalParam48=value48 -DOptionalParam49=value49

Comment: So why can't you just have -DoptionalParam48=value48 in the jenkins job if you are checking for these parameters in gradle either? What's the advantage of having -DAdditionalParameters=-DoptionalParam48=value48

Comment: In order for me to get a -DoptionalParam48=value48 passed to gradle from jenkins, I would have to add an new paramter "optionalParam48" in Jenkins "paramterized build". Likewise, each of the 1-50 parameters would need the same approach and this makes the Jenkins parameter page ugly. This is the reason I was contemplating a generic "OptionalParamters" approach. With an OptionalParamters, i can have as many name=value pair passed to Gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Jenkins passes the parameters to Gradle, they are set as Systems Properties. The task now is to parse the "-DoptionalParam1=value1 -DOptionalParam2=value2" passed as an "Additional Parameters" and then pass these further to the Java application as JVM paramters. Below is the Gralde code snippet that does it. To simplify the "Additional Paramter" is passed as "optionalParam1=value1 OptionalParam2=value2", ie without the -D syntax.

```
    task runJavaApp(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: build) {

        def jvmParams = []
        project.gradle.startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs.entrySet().each{
        if (it.key!="Additional Parameters") {
            jvmParams <<  "-D${it.key}=${it.value}"
        } else {
            def tokens = (it.value).split(/\s{1,}/)
            tokens.each {
                def key, value
                if (it.split('=').length == 2)
                    (key, value )= it.split('=')
                else
                    throw new Exception("'${it}' should be of type key=value");
                jvmParams <<  "-D${key}=${value}"
                }
            }//if
        }
        jvmArgs jvmParams
        workingDir = project.executeDir
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + files(project.executeDir)
        main = 'myApplicaionMainClass'
    }
```